# Yammer: How to get thread id of a particular post?

Tags: yammer

If we are posting a message at Yammer using Java and later want to retrieve the same message using its thread id, then how can we get that particular message's thread id?

Answer (score 0):

The thread ID should match the original message ID of your thread starter (the first message in the thread.) You can see this if you post the first message in a thread, reply to it, and then delete the first message (which leaves only your reply.)

Looking at the API response for the thread you'll see that the thread ID matches the original message ID which you deleted. My steps above are more than you actually need to observe the behaviour, but it helps confirm that the thread ID doesn't mutate.